IIS failed to open one page with faulting module (System.ni.dll) error
We host ASP.NET Framework 4.8 on IIS, same application, multiple sites and for each site different port and different Application pool.
One of the sites has an issue in one page when we try to open it, site failed, and in the event viewer we found this error:

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.20348.1, time
stamp: 0x405e4c14 Faulting module name: System.ni.dll, version:
4.8.4644.0, time stamp: 0x645319fc Exception code: 0xc00000fd Fault offset: 0x00000000002d92c0 Faulting process id: 0x85b0 Faulting
application start time: 0x01daabb1943ac67f Faulting application path:
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path:
C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\67fa5133f5ad6ab200b2f6f043287ddc\System.ni.dll
Report Id: 75f4accb-ab17-4004-80dd-3ec952030d0a Faulting package full
name:  Faulting package-relative application ID:


The Win32 error code 0xc00000fd corresponds to STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW. This error indicates that a stack overflow has occurred in a program or process and in your case you need to analyze the crash further with a debugger.

@YurongDai The tool you mentioned capture (Windows) process dumps, not "thread dumps" (which is specific to Java).

@Lex Li Thank you for your correction.

When the server hangs or crashes, it is usually necessary to capture the server's process dumps for subsequent analysis. The debug diagnostic tool (DebugDiag) can be a lifesaver. You can refer to: IIS Application Pool Crash and Debug Diag. It creates and analyzes IIS crash dumps. After seeing the call stack, you may be able to figure out the cause of the crash.
